# Windows 10 won't boot (invalid signature)

Tags: grub2

To access my dual boot Windows 10 I go F9 and then select EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.

Windows 10 wouldn't boot from grub list.

GPT /dev/sda

```
Disk /dev/sda: 698.64 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Disk model: HGST HTS541075A9
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E4ED9C9D-ABFD-4D05-920C-DE27136C18A0
```

I am here because BIOS settings are not saved. I can't enable UEFI so I am in Legacy mode (or CSM). What options I will have in order to boot Windows from grub?

the efi partition /dev/sda4 is mounted on /boot/efi

Windows is on /dev/sda4 because was installed after linux (ubuntu is on /dev/sda2)

/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

grub:

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  6A90-785A
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6A90-785A
fi
chainloader /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
```

Comment: The usual Microsoft bootloader is /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi, and looks like it should be on sda2, not sda4.  Did you perhaps make another EFI partition?  There should only be one.

Comment: I had that initially but got the same error. Thanks for trying :)

Comment: Windows on a GPT disk is in UEFI mode, and cannot be booted from grub in legacy mode.  Why do you think bootx64.efi is Windows?  After grub installs, it replaces bootx64.efi (originally the Windows bootloader), with itself or shim.  Check the sizes of bootx64.efi and grubx64.efi, shimx64.efi, and bootmgfw.efi.  If Windows is installed on sda4, it should not be mounted at /boot.efi.  Maybe run the boot-repair just for the report (make no changes), and post the link.